# Comma separate jQuery selectable items

Tags: jquery, selectable

I am using jQuery and the widget Selectable to let my user select files to delete.
I am appending each selection to a div to be able to see what divs I have selected.
I need to comma seperate the values (ids) to be able to use it when saving.

How can I comma seperate? Is there a better way of doing this?

```
$("#photo_area").selectable({

                cancel: 'a',

                stop: function() {

                    var result = $("#selected").empty();

                    $(".ui-selected", this).each(function() {

                        var index = $(this).attr('id');

                        result.append(index);

                    });

                }

            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing blatantly wrong with what you already have, but I think the following is a *little* more concise:

```
var ids = $(this).find(".ui-selected").map(function() {
    return this.id;
}).get().join(",");
```

- http://api.jquery.com/map/

Comment: That looks very interesting! How can I "read" the result of this? Output it into a div or a textfield?

Comment: Simply: `$("#selected").html(ids)`

Comment: Tried that but this makes the comma appear twice in some places, like this: 1,,2,3,4,,5.

Comment: If you are using firefox with firebug installed just use `console.log(ids)`

Comment: It outputs the same in firebug.

Comment: That's odd. Do you have commas in your IDs? Can you post the code which is resulting in the double commas?

Comment: It almost happen every time I "drag" to select. Less often if I click once per div. This is my jQuery code. http://pastie.org/3281789. This is my HTML code: http://pastie.org/3281800.

Comment: Perhaps I can use my original code and just add to an array for each iteration? But how can I then use that array when saving?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are after. But you can always use a comma speerated string as a jQuery selector.

```
$('#myId2, #myId1, #myId3')
```

..fredrik